# method overloading Visual Studio

Tags: c#, database, class, overloading

I am doing a project. This project involves a database with a table called 'Customers'. In the same project, I have a form called 'frmAddNewCustomer'. This form takes in 9 attributes relating to the customer. There is a button that when clicked has code that allows these attributes to be entered into the database respectively.

I also have a class called 'CustomerDAL' that allows me to performs tasks on the database table (Insert, Update, Delete etc.) and class holds the method that I used to enter data into the database from the 'frmAddNewCustomer' form.

Finally, I have a class called 'CustomerModel' which represents a record in the database. In the CustomerDAL class, the parameters for the method mentioned earlier (the one that allows me to enter data to the database through the UI form) are an object created from the CustomerModel class. my problem is that in the UI form it says that the method has no overload for 9 arguments.

This is the customer model class:

```
public int CustomerID { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set; }
public string Forename { get; set; }
public string Surname { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }
public string Streetname { get; set; }

public string Town { get; set; }
public string County { get; set; }
public string Postcode { get; set; }
public string WeddingGiftList { get; set; }

public CustomerModel( string title, string forename, string surname, string email, string  streetname,string town, string county, string postcode, string weddingGiftlist)
{
        Title = title;
        Forename = forename;
        Surname = surname;
        Email = email;
        Streetname = streetname;
        Town = town;
        County = county;
        Postcode = postcode;
        WeddingGiftList = weddingGiftlist;
}

public CustomerModel()
{
}
```

This is the CustomerDAL class:

```
 private static string _connectionString =       ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SimpsonsConnection"].ConnectionString;

    public static int AddNewCustomer(CustomerModel newCustomer)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            string sqlQuery = string.Format("INSERT INTO [Customer] VALUES('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}')", newCustomer.Title, newCustomer.Forename, newCustomer.Surname, newCustomer.Email, newCustomer.Streetname, newCustomer.Town, newCustomer.County, newCustomer.Postcode, newCustomer.WeddingGiftList);

            SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection);

            int rowsAffected = insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            connection.Close();

            return rowsAffected;
        }
    }

//this is the UI forms click event on the button:

//this is to add the customer details to the database when the 'Create button is clicked'
   if ( cmbxTitle.Text != "" || txtForename.Text != "" || txtSurname.Text != "" || txtEmail.Text != "" || txtStreetName.Text != "" || txtTown.Text != "" || txtCounty.Text != "" || txtPostCode.Text != "" || cmbxWeddingGiftList.Text != "")
        {
            int rowsAffected = CustomerDAL.AddNewCustomer(cmbxTitle.Text, txtForename.Text, txtSurname.Text, txtEmail.Text, txtStreetName.Text, txtTown.Text, txtCounty.Text, txtPostCode.Text, cmbxWeddingGiftList.Text);

            if(rowsAffected == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Customer has been added successfully");

                Form myNextScreen = new frmMenu();
                myNextScreen.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Customer was not able to be registered. Please re-enter details carefully");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lblInfo.Visible = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter all details");
        }
```

In the UI form my error is when I reference the 'AddNewCustomer' method from the CustomerDAL class.

[error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAT3s.png)

I'm just not sure how to fix this error as I think I have 9 arguments?
It would mean a lot if you could help me with this as I'm relatively new to databases in C#

Comment: some of that code didn't get formatted properly but it should still be readable

Comment: Also while [edit] the post make sure to include error message as text into the post as well as clean up the code to be [mre].

Comment: addnewcustomer takes one argument

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, your problem can be in not defining the object

```
int rowsAffected = CustomerDAL.AddNewCustomer(new CustomerModel{....});
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of this

```
int rowsAffected = CustomerDAL.AddNewCustomer(cmbxTitle.Text, txtForename.Text, txtSurname.Text, txtEmail.Text, txtStreetName.Text, txtTown.Text, txtCounty.Text, txtPostCode.Text, cmbxWeddingGiftList.Text);
```

have this

```
var newCustomer = new Customer
{
    Title  = cmbxTitle.Text,
//rest of customer properties
};
int rowsAffected = CustomerDAL.AddNewCustomer(newCustomer)
```